# How can I make a multiple correlation?

Tags: r

My data is made of 59 variables (columns) and 500 observations (each participant). I have to make a correlation of one item (column) with the rest of items (all other columns).

I made this for the first column to the others, but I would like to repeat the operation in a for loop.

I tried :

```
sapply(mydata[-1],function(y)cor.test(mydata$First_Item,y)$p.value)
```

But if I would do it for the 2nd column on the 1st column and the 3:59 others, it doesn't work.

I would like a thing like that :

```
for (i in 1:59){
    sapply(mydata[,i],function(y)cor.test(mydata[,i],y)$p.value)
}
```

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT :**

```
B1_TP_CO_9999_01 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1) 
B1_TP_CO_9999_02 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
B1_TP_CO_9999_03 = c(2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0) 
B1_TP_CO_9999_04 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0) 
B1_TP_CO_9999_05 = c(0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `?cor` function will create the correlation matrix nice and quick. But if you want a custom function, such as to make the p-value easy, just try a double loop. Not the fastest, but very simple.

```
mydata <- matrix(runif(200),20,10)
p <- ncol(mydata)

cor_pval <- function(x, y) cor.test(x, y)$p.value
m <- matrix(0, p, p)

for (i in 1:ncol(mydata)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(mydata)) {
    m[i,j] = cor_pval(mydata[,i], mydata[,j])
  }
}
```

This is pretty brute force. You don't need the function if you do not want it, but it makes it easy to change the metric. Also instead of doing every column in the second loop, you can start `j` from `i+1` so as to not duplicate calculations. But, this should get your result, and you can tune from there as you figure out the loops.

Also here it is with the apply function as you were doing. If you are going to build the results back in the matrix, you need to slot in 0 for the location of the vector `i=j` from the `for` loop.

```
m2 <- matrix(0, p, p)
for (i in 1:p) {
 m2[i, ] = append(apply(mydata[,-i], 2, cor_pval, y = mydata[,i]), 0, after = i - 1)
}

all.equal(m, m2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `expand.grid()` to avoid nested loops.

```
n <- ncol(mydata)
ex <- t(expand.grid(1:n, 1:n))                         # transpose with `t()`

myCor <- function(x) cor.test(x[, 1], x[, 2])$p.value  # test fun
```

Now we run a single `sapply()` and pack the result into a matrix with the right dimnames.

```
MX <- matrix(sapply(seq(ncol(ex)), function(i) myCor(mydata[ex[, i]])), 
             ncol=n, dimnames=rep(list(names(mydata)), 2))
```

*Yielding:*

```
MX <- round(MX, 3)
```

```
> MX
                 B1_TP_CO_9999_01 B1_TP_CO_9999_02 B1_TP_CO_9999_03 B1_TP_CO_9999_04 B1_TP_CO_9999_05
B1_TP_CO_9999_01            0.000               NA            0.043            1.000            0.757
B1_TP_CO_9999_02               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA
B1_TP_CO_9999_03            0.043               NA            0.000            0.857            0.703
B1_TP_CO_9999_04            1.000               NA            0.857            0.000            0.164
B1_TP_CO_9999_05            0.757               NA            0.703            0.164            0.000
```

A test shows us, that this is working:

```
> cor.test(mydata[, 1], mydata[, 3])$p.value
[1] 0.04325627
> cor.test(mydata[, 4], mydata[, 3])$p.value
[1] 0.8574056
> cor.test(mydata[, 4], mydata[, 5])$p.value
[1] 0.164388
```

If we want to get rid of the upper triangle we finally could do

```
MX[upper.tri(MX, diag=TRUE)] <- ""
```

leading to:

```
> as.data.frame(MX)[-n]
                 B1_TP_CO_9999_01 B1_TP_CO_9999_02 B1_TP_CO_9999_03 B1_TP_CO_9999_04
B1_TP_CO_9999_01                                                                    
B1_TP_CO_9999_02             <NA>                                                   
B1_TP_CO_9999_03            0.043             <NA>                                  
B1_TP_CO_9999_04                1             <NA>            0.857                 
B1_TP_CO_9999_05            0.757             <NA>            0.703            0.164
```

*Note:* The warnings stem from your data, you could alternatively test the code e.g. with `mydata <- iris[-5]`.

***Data***

```
mydata <- structure(list(B1_TP_CO_9999_01 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), B1_TP_CO_9999_02 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), B1_TP_CO_9999_03 = c(2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0), B1_TP_CO_9999_04 = c(0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), B1_TP_CO_9999_05 = c(0, 
2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```